# Infinite Scroll Changing ID issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infinite-scroll

I'm currently having issues with infinite scroll, my itemSelector ID changes for each li. It's not grabbing the next page `<li>`

Example:

```
<ul class="e-list e-list-entity">
    <li id="e-user-366430" class="e-item"></li>
    <li id="e-user-345435" class="e-item"></li>
    <li id="e-user-345345" class="e-item"></li>
    <li id="e-user-234344" class="e-item"></li>
</ul>
```

I'm using the following for the container and item selector

```
$container = $('.e-list-entity');
itemSelector : '#e-user',
```

is this the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

itemSelector should rather be:

```
itemSelector : '.e-item'
```

You have no element with id '#e-user'.

> From the (very old) [documentation](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/):
>   itemSelector: selector for all items you'll retrieve

Edit based on comments:

If you have two, or more, instances you'll need to make sure the selectors are still unique. For example, the following setup would be unique:

```
<ul id="firstScroller" class="e-list e-list-entity">
    <li id="e-user-366430" class="e-item"></li>
</ul>

itemSelector : '#firstScroller .e-item'
```

and the second..

```
<ul id="secondScroller" class="e-list e-list-entity">
    <li id="e-user-366430" class="e-item"></li>
</ul>

itemSelector : '#secondScroller .e-item'
```

Comment: This almost worked, I updated my code above to add the class i have in each <li> (Didnt know this would cause a issue). when i use the itemSelector you stated, it grabs the next li but doesnt add the class that goes with the li

Comment: So it works now if you do: itemSelector : '.e-item' ?

Comment: My original issue is I have two infinite scrolls on the same page one shows members posts and the other shows members, When infinite scroll is triggered it grabs from both of the lists and displays it only want the current list displayed.  Sorry thought it would of been a simple task